# cv::Mat will be changed after inserting it into a std::map? What is the underlying reason?

Tags: c++, opencv

I meet this problem when I deal with image streams from multi-cameras. I create a map and put all images into it based on the camera id, so I have:

```cpp
std::mat<uint32_t, cv::Mat> images;
```

I will add image into that map by calling `addImages` as soon as receiving data from a specific camera:

```cpp
void addImages(uint32_t camera_id, CameraData imgData)
{
  cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(imgData.height(), imgData.width(), CV_8UC3, (void *)imgData.ptr);
  images.insert(make_pair(camera_id, img));
  cv::imshow("origin image", img);
}
```

When I show images from that map somewhere else, strange thing happens. The image changes and I can tell that its color differs from the original one.

```cpp
void showImage(uint32_t camera_id)
{
  cv::imshow("get image", images[camera_id]);
  cv::waitKey(1);
}
```

But when I change `addImages` codes a little bit, images are same as original ones which is expected.

```cpp
void addImages(uint32_t camera_id, CameraData imgData)
{
  cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(imgData.height(), imgData.width(), CV_8UC3, (void *)imgData.ptr);
  
  // NOTE THIS LINE!!! 
  images.insert(make_pair(camera_id, img.clone()));


  cv::imshow("origin image", img);
}
```

So, my question is, what is the difference? Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This line seems incorrect.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(imgData.height(), imgData.width(), CV_8UC3, (void *)imgData.ptr);
```

Here's a quote from the documentation on the fourth parameter to this constructor

> Pointer to the user data. Matrix constructors that take data and step
> parameters do not allocate matrix data. Instead, they just initialize
> the matrix header that points to the specified data, which means that
> no data is copied.

In other words the `Mat` object just stores this pointer, it doesn't copy the data from it.

Now when your `addImages` function exits it destroys the `imgData` object which (presumably) invalidates the pointer you have just stored in the `img` object. That results in the problem you see.

The second version creates a clone of the `img` object which does copy the image data and so breaks the connection between the `img` object and the `imgData` object.

You might be able to fix this problem by passing the `imgData` parameter by reference. This means the `imgData` object would not be destroyed at the end of the function. But you would still have a situation where the `Mat` object and the `CameraData` object are sharing image data. So that might not be a good solution, but only you could say that for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @john. This makes sense.